# Get rid of warning produces by Collections.unmodifiableList()

Tags: java, generics, collections

Following code produces this warning:

Warning:

```
 Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<TableModel>
```

Code:

```
List<TableModel> tableModels = new ArrayList<TableModel>();
List<TableModel> list = Collections.unmodifiableList(tableModels);
```

The method signature is:

```
public static <T> List<T> unmodifiableList(List<? extends T> list)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: List<MclsTableModel> is not used in you're code, can you post the original ? There is now warning if you use it as your Code snippet suggests. Check the declared type of the collection you are trying to lock.

Comment: There should be no warning in this case. Are you sure it is `List<TableModel> list` and not `List list`?

Comment: Sorry, '<TableModel>' was supposed to be also in the warning.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for:

```
List<TableModel> list = Collections.<TableModel>unmodifiableList(tableModels);
```

Comment: Thanks for tip. Actually it was a mistake. Collections' imported were not from 'java.util' but from other package.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this issue when compiling code that I received from a colleague. Turns out I was using the Java 7 instead of Java 8 compiler. Switching to 8 solved it for me.